# Every finite group $G$ such that $p\mid |G|$ has a maximal p-subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I'm reading the book "An Introduction to the Theory of Groups" by Joseph Rotman. Maximal $p$-subgroup is defined as: $P$ is a maximal $p$-subgroup of a group $G$ if for every $Q\le G$, $Q$ is a $p$-subgroup and $P\le Q$, then $P=Q$.

1º Wouldn't a subgroup, $M$, of order $m>1$ such that $\gcd(m,p) = 1$ be a maximal $p$-subgroup, since there is no $p$-subgroup which contains $M$ as subgroup?

The author then proceeds to prove the Sylow Theorems, in the proof he considers the set $X=\{P_1,P_2...,P_r\}$ the family of all conjugates of $P$, a maximal $p$-subgroup.

2ºHow can we be sure that this set is not empty? In other words how can we be sure that every finite group $G$, such that $p\mid |G|$ has a maximal $p$-subgroup?

Comment: The definition of "maximal $p$-subgroup" surely includes that $P$ is itself a $p$-subgroup. Otherwise the name doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, because $M$ is not a $p$-subgroup.
2. By Cauchy theorem, $G$ has an element of order $p$, hence a cyclic sugroup of order $p$. Thus, the set of $p$-subgroups of $G$ is not empty. Take any $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$ with maximal order (which does exist since $G$ is finite. Note that such a $P$ is not necessarily unique). Now, if $Q$ is a $p$-subgroup containing $P$, $\vert P\vert\leq\vert Q\vert $. By maximality of the order of $P$ among the orders of $p$-subgroups, $\vert Q\vert\leq\vert P\vert.$ Hence $P$ and $Q$ have same order, and since $Q$ contains $P$, $Q=P$.  Hence, $P$ is a maximal $p$-subgroup.